# Can I run IntelliJ unit tests in a maven project without re-running maven goals?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit

I have a project with a deep maven structure and am evaluating switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ.

I've imported the top-level pom.xml. I know that I can:

1. Build the whole project with maven goals (I use 'test-compile' to build the test classes)
2. Run the tests from the IntelliJ test runner. This seems to find the classes/test-classes from the target folder of the project.

However, I would like to just change a test or the code under test, save it, and rerun it without having to manually run the maven test-compile again (like I could with Eclipse). Is this possible with IntelliJ?

I think the issue is that the IntelliJ 'Build Project' action does not build the test classes (and other classes) into the target folder that the test runner looks in.

Comment: First you should import the whole project into IntelliJ or into Eclipse. You can simply rerun a test (by clicking on the test) after a code change within the IDE (both Eclipse/IntelliJ) otherwise there is something wrong...apart from that does your build run fine on plain command line?

Comment: I have imported the whole project in to IntelliJ. Rerunning a test seems to run the test in the state that it was in when last built into target/test-classes. In fact if I rebuild the project, it clears out any .class files from target, and trying to run tests again reports "Class not found".

Comment: There is something really wrong...BTW: Which IDEA version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion from @CrazyCoder, I was able to get this working by following these steps, as I think the issue was Eclipse artifacts fighting with IntelliJ artifacts:

1. Remove all .classpath, .project and .iml files from the entire code tree
2. Remove .idea from the root - we need to start again
3. Open the top-level pom.xml in IntelliJ
4. If needed, perform a `mvn compile` (needed for me due to some generated sources)
5. Rebuild your project

After this, don't open your project in Eclipse again!

Comment: Additionally, at one time I ended up opening IntelliJ from the command line, and for some reason it opened at the parent folder. So instead of opening at C:\dev\myProject, it opened C:\dev. This meant that there was an IntelliJ config folder created C:\dev\.idea. 

When I closed and opened again at the right location, it seemed to work, but I was unable to run tests reliably from the IDE because some paths were messed up in .iml files. The solution was to remove C:\dev\.idea, C:\dev\myProject\.idea, all *.iml files, and start again.

Answer (score 3):

If you import a Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA, you will be able to build and run the tests from the IDE instead of Maven which is a lot faster because of the incremental compilation.

Make sure [this option is disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emNsQ.png) and use JUnit Run/Debug configuration, don't run the maven goals.

Comment: I do have that option disabled and am using IntelliJ Run/Debug. I really feel that the issue is that the Test runner is only looking in /target for the test classes and the IntelliJ build puts them somewhere else.

Comment: Test runner should be using classpath instead of the hardcoded directories. IntelliJ IDEA output is not shared with Maven, it's by design, but it should not affect properly written apps and tests that do not rely on the output directory location.

Comment: Okay... is there something I can debug to see why this is not happening?

Comment: See the classpath in the command line of the test when you start if from the IDE. Does it contain the output directories? Do these output directories have the required .class files and the resources? Do the classes appear in these output directories after you use Build | Build? Is there any configuration in your tests that references `target` directory explicitly? [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be appreciated if you want to get help here.